# View display wrong behavior when there's a required="true" within the body

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a view which is working well. However, when I add a required="true" into the body of the view, the view begin to be unable to read backing bean properly. Below is a comparison:

Anyone knows why?

[image: Without required="true"]
[image: Wit required="true"]
.

**Edit: Code fragment supplement**

Below is the fragment of my code in which the problem arises. If I add **required="true"** into any p:inputText (not only the p:inputText that belong to this dialog but any p:inputText inside the html body), it stops displaying information from backing bean, remove it and everything works just fine.

```
<p:dialog header="Customer Editor" widgetVar="customerEditDialog"
                resizable="false" id="customerEditDlg" showEffect="fade"
                hideEffect="fade" modal="true">

                <h:panelGrid id="editGrid" columns="2" cellpadding="4"
                    style="margin:0 auto;">

                    <h:outputLabel for="customerNameEdit" value="Name: " />
                    <p:inputText id="customerNameEdit" maxlength="30"
                        value="#{customerController.customerAdd.name}" />
                    <h:outputLabel for="customerPhoneNumberEdit" value="Phone Number " />
                    <p:inputText id="customerPhoneNumberEdit" maxlength="15"
                        onkeypress="if(event.which  &lt; 48 || event.which  &gt; 57) return false;"
                        value="#{customerController.customerAdd.phoneNumber}" />
                    <h:outputLabel for="customerEmailEdit" value="Email: " />
                    <p:inputText id="customerEmailEdit" maxlength="49"
                        value="#{customerController.customerAdd.email}" />
                    <h:outputLabel for="customerAddressEdit" value="Address: " />
                    <p:inputText id="customerAddressEdit" maxlength="190"
                        value="#{customerController.customerAdd.address}" />
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <div style="text-align: right">
                            <p:commandButton id="editCustomerButton"
                                update=":form:customerList, :form:messages"
                                oncomplete="customerEditDialog.hide()" value="Save"
                                actionListener="#{customerController.editCustomer()}">
                            </p:commandButton>

                            <p:commandButton id="cancelEditCustomerButton" update=":form"
                                onclick="customerEditDialog.hide()" value="Cancel">
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </div>
                    </f:facet>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Please post an SSCCE. The phrase *"adding required=true into body of view"* is also strange and rather ambiguous, by the way. Don't you mean *"adding required=true to input components"*? That part works just fine for me (and likely also everyone else). Again, please post an SSCCE so that we can copy'n'paste'n'run and see it ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [jsf required=true destroys setPropertyActionListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876118/jsf-required-true-destroys-setpropertyactionlistener) helps you.

The problem is most likely that the setter in your bean is not to be called because of validation errors somewhere else or you are nesting `<h:form>` elements.