# jsf required=true destroys setPropertyActionListener?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Using primefaces 4.0 and jsf 2.2.5

stmt.xhtml has 2 includes. IncludeDetail.xhtml and IncludeDuo.xhtml. IncludeDuo also includes IncludeDetail.

In **IncludeDetail.xhtml** the `<ui:composition>` Element owns no `<form>`, `id`-Attribute or any other special elements. Only `<h:panelGrid>`, `<h:selectOneMenu>` and `<h:selectOneMenu>`. Nothing special.

**IncludeDuo.xhtml** owns  `<p:layout>` and `<p:message>` as child elements of `<ui:composition>`. Deeper inside the `<p:layout>` we find this piece of code:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="padding-left: 10px">
   <h:outputText value="AS" />
      <h:selectManyMenu value="#{regelBean.selectedASForNewElement}" required="true" style="height:115px">
         <f:selectItems value="#{aSBean.elementList}" var="var" itemLabel="#{var.vaSl}"
                    itemValue="#{var.vaSl}" />
   </h:selectManyMenu>
</h:panelGrid>
```

If I remove `required="true"` everything works as expected. If I leave it there, the following setPropertyActionListener won't do it's job anymore:

```
<h:form id="form1">
        <p:dialog header="Neue Regel" widgetVar="newDuoDialog" resizable="false" id="newDuoDlg" showEffect="fade"
            hideEffect="fade" modal="true" styleClass="newDialog" width="1220">
            <ui:insert name="insertDuo">
                <ui:include src="/includes/duoRegelStmt.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:dialog>
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" life="20000"/>
        <div class="nvg-dataTable">
            <p:dataTable id="dt1" var="tVar" value="#{stmtBean.elementList}"
                scrollable="false" styleClass="nvg-mainTable" paginator="true"
                paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" rows="10"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,100" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                currentPageReportTemplate="({startRecord}-{endRecord} von {totalRecords})"
                emptyMessage="Keine Statements gefunden" filteredValue="#{stmtBean.filteredElements}">

                <p:column styleClass="padding2" style="width:6%">
                    <p:commandButton value="?" update=":dlgForm"
                        oncomplete="PF('detDialog').show()" icon="" title="Detail">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{tVar}" target="#{stmtBean.selectedElement}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="N" update=""
                        oncomplete="PF('newDuoDialog').show()" icon="" title="Neue Regel mit diesem Statement als Grundlage">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{tVar}" target="#{stmtBean.selectedElement}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
[ ... ]
```

Is this a bug or am I misusing sth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour: As you are setting the property on submit of the form the property is only set when the form is successfully submitted, which is not the case when validation fails i.e. a required field is empty.

Use `process="@this"` on the `p:commandButton` so the form is not submitted. This should work for you as you just want to open the dialog and set the property.